# Office UI Fabric reponsive or fluid?

Tags: office-ui-fabric

Looking through the documentation it seems like Office UI Fabric grid is fluid only and not responsive like bootstrap. Can anyone confirm or reject this?

[Sample on office ui grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEKuF.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Office UI Fabric Core](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core) is flexible enough to produce both fluid and responsive layout. As you mention correctly the example on the documentation website has a luck of responsive UI layout, but it doesn't mean it is not supported. To confirm this look at [Responsive Grid](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-core/blob/master/src/documentation/pages/Responsive-Grid/index.html) page and find `ms-Grid-row` and `ms-Grid-col` classes provided. You are able to use any of those to get a responsive grid, you want to achieve.

Even more: if you will be using controls provided by [Office UI Fabric JS](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js) most of them are responsive to screen size already and you may override the default behavior as well.

And even more: The [Office Fabric UI website](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/) itself uses its own responsive grid. To see the example in action just use this link, go to the website and try to re-size the browser window.

EDIT:

On March 12, 2020 Microsoft announced [UI Fabric is evolving into Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/ui-fabric-is-evolving-into-fluent-ui/). The new packages should be used. More from official [GitHub repo ...](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui)

Comment: Thanks very helpfull!

Comment: Links are dead.

Comment: @ChrisGessler The links ad recommendations are updated. Thanks.